# Nginx Rewrite Short URL

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-config

i have this currently as my configuration:

```
location /read_article {
            rewrite ^/read_article/([0-9/-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9/-]+)/?$ /read_article.php?title=$1 last;
    }

    location /users {
            rewrite ^/users/([A-Za-z0-9/-]+)/?$ /ajax.php?todo=$1 last;
    }
    location /login {
            rewrite ^/login$ /login.php last;
    }
    location /logout {
            rewrite ^/logout$ /logout.php last;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
```

however, I want to configure nginx so that if a user goes to website.com/{articleid} it will take him to a shortened version of the article so say it would be rewritten to short_article.php?id={id}

for example

```
website.com/s2s3fw -> short_article.php?id=s2s3fw
```

while keeping the rest of the routes working...

Comment: You can do that in the `location /` block. The question is which URIs should be directed to `/index.html`?

Comment: no sure I understand?

Comment: You have an `/index.html` in the last `server` block in your question. Currently,  `website.com/s2s3fw` is directed to `/index.html`. What (if any) URIs should still go to `/index.html`? Or do you just want to change the `try_files` statement to `location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /short_article.php?id=$uri;`?